# Remote Git server for Pycharm

Tags: git, version-control, pycharm

Started developing Python using Pycharm and would like to set up a remote Git Server for wider team work. 
I already just set Bonobo up but can't seem to get Pycharm to work with it. Little experience in this area.

Is the right approach being attempted here ? Will Bonobo work with Pycharm ?
Any better open source solution available to work with Pycharm ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyCharm offers great support and own tools for working with git!

Check out the official doc here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/version-control-with-pycharm.html?origin=old_help

If you already have initialized a git repository in your project folder, PyCharm should automatically suggest enabling VCS (Version Control Support). Otherwise just do a `git init`.
Make sure to add the remote repository from your Bonobo-server via `git remote add ...`

Furthermore, set up a proper *.gitignore* file, for user-specific settings in PyCharm. Check out this example .gitginore: https://www.gitignore.io/api/pyc%2Cpycharm%2Cpython

Regarding your question whether Bonobo will work with PyCharm:
PyCharm doesn't care what service is running your remote git server.
I have no experience with Bonobo, but was using [GitLab](https://gitlab.com) for various projects in different team sizes. It's great.

Comment: Cheers - Spent a while now looking through provided references and info. not sure I have managed to move forward though. Really need a step by step in getting this setup. So far managed to put the project root under Github VCS (in Pycharm) which essentially creates a .git directory at the project root. I can't see any option though to point over to the remote repository that is setup. The url that I need to use is clear enough being admin@sqlserver2012/bonobo/myProject.git. But getting Pycharm pointing to this repository is still a mystery.

Comment: Pycharm doesn't have to do much with adding the remote git server to your local project. It provides just a GUI for git workflows. To add the remote repository run git remote add origin [your_remote_url]

Comment: Been trying a number of things to try and put my project in to empty repository. Based on what I read here: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Getting-Git-on-a-Server I ran: "git clone --bare my_project my_project.git" . The new my_project.git I copied in to the Bonobo repo dir however when cloning or opening via Pycharm I get an empty project. Commits and push work however the question is how to upload existing Pycharm in to new repo.

Comment: As a suggestion, since this is more about learning Git and using Bonobo, perhaps add a tag to your question related to git to try and get some people with experience on it.

Comment: @dross just forget about PyCharm for now.
The steps to do are: 1. go into the local directory, that should be the root of your git repository. Run 'git init' in a terminal / git bash. 2. Create an empty git repository on your Bonobo-server. Bonobo hopefully gives you an ssh/https url for this newly created repository. 3. In your local git repo, add the remote repo via: git remote add origin <url-of-remote>. 4. To 'publish' your local project to Bonobo run: 'git add . && git commit -m "Init" && git push origin master'. 5. After this setup you can use PyCharm to work with git.

Comment: @Max - this works to a point. The point being is that I need to keep running command number 4 from the command line in order to ensure the changes made via Pycharm get committed to remote repo. If I run the Pycharm commit it only seems to commit locally.

Comment: @dross Yes. PyCharm is not auto-pushing every commit. You can push via VCS > git > Push...

Comment: @Max - Understood and now working now as you describe.